# Actionscript 3: How do I measure the time between mouse events...?

Tags: actionscript-3, time, actionscript, mouseevent, timing

I'm trying to get a dial to rotate at a different rate depending on how fast you spin the mouse scroll button.

So far I have a spinning object and can count the number of turns you do.

I'm now trying to find the time between each event so I can then speed up or slow down the next event accordingly.

This is what I have so far:

```
var scaler_1 = 1;
var rotation_value = 1;
var number_value = 1;
var cCount = 1;
var myTimer:Timer=new Timer(1000,0);


import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.utils.setInterval;

stage.frameRate = 24;

function handleMouseWheel(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    myTimer.start();



    movieClip_1.rotation += event.delta/scaler_1;

    rotation_value += event.delta;

    number_value += event.delta/scaler_1;




    //output for reference

     angle_1.text=String(movieClip_1.rotation); 

     number_1.text=String(number_value);
     time_1.text=String("timer " +myTimer );


      cCount = cCount+1;
      count_1.text=String("count " + cCount);


    //keep within 1000 numbers
     if(number_value < 0){
            number_value = 999
     }
     if(number_value >= 1000){
            number_value = 0
     }


     myTimer.stop();
}

myTimer.reset();
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, handleMouseWheel);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a Timer because it is inaccurate you can measure the elapsed time by using getTimer() method or Date.time. In general in first event get value from getTimer() or new Date().time and store it than into next event check the difference between the new value from getTimer() or time. The difference is the elapsed time in milliseconds. Store the new value and so on.